# Bootstrap v4 navbar breakpoint

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am facing a problem for one of the project. The mobile layout is not working on the same web application on different pages.

Any page on this url: [IndianStandups](https://indianstandups.com/), when using chrome inspector tools and trying mobile layout is, the navigation bar is properly rendered.

Though only [About Page](https://indianstandups.com/about) doesn't show properly on mobile layout.

Any guidance is appreciated on how can I debug this issue as there is no difference in CSS and JS on both the pages.

This navigation is shown properly.

[image: Working Nav Bar]

---

The navigation is very small. Seems like the css breakpoint is not being detected.

[image: Not working nav]

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'doesn't show properly'?

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshots. As you can see in the second image, the navigation bar is very not rendered as to be in mobile view. 
Though in the first image, the navigation bar is more bigger and rendered as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this meta tag in your HTML document's head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

This has been stated in [Bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag).

Comment: Thank you so much. I had it in every page but removed for my master template. Since my about page was inheriting from that, didn't had that.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help you!